# EditText set error

Tags: android, android-edittext

im trying to set error on my edit text if the user perssed the login button without fill the text fields. I have tried several codes , but nothing helped. The application was crashing every time i ran it.

**this this is the code**

```
    public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {

private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
EditText email,password;
Button login;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_login_fragment, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    firebaseAuth = firebaseAuth.getInstance();

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

    login = (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
    email = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.regEmailEt);
    password = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.regPasswordEt);


    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        String email1;
        String password1;
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(email.getText().length() == 0){
                    email.setError("Please enter your email");
                }
                if(password.getText().length() == 0){
                    password.setError("Please enter your password");
                }

                     email1 = email.getText().toString();
                     password1 = password.getText().toString();

                progressDialog.setMessage("Processing...");
                progressDialog.show();


                   FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email1, password1)
                           .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                               @Override
                               public void onComplete(Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                   if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                       startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class));
                                       progressDialog.dismiss();
                                   }
                               }
                           }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onFailure(Exception e) {
                           Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error:" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                           progressDialog.dismiss();
                       }
                   });
               }

        });

       }
   }
```

when the login button pressed it should active the setOnClickListener.
there i want to check if the text fields are empty, if they are so i want to setError in the textEdit. else , i want it to continue. 
I'm pretty sure that my code is wrong, so i need your advise guys.

**Crash Log**

```
     02-18 19:32:46.012 11162-11162/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: com.world.bolandian.whereareyou, PID: 11162
                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
                                                   at com.world.bolandian.whereareyou.LoginFragment$1.onClick(LoginFragment.java:52)
                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5207)
                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21177)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
```

**line 52**
line 52 is -> if(email.getText().length()==0)

Comment: post your log cat, and where is your edit text, I never saw some one finding IDs like this in fragment `login = (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);`   where are all your buttons located . In activity ? or Fragment? .we have to use `onViewCreated()` method to find ids in fragments

Comment: the button is placed in the fragment

Comment: i have posted the log cat

Answer (score 0):

```
 String email1;
    String password1;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(email.getText().length() == 0){
                email.setError("Please enter your email");
            }
            if(password.getText().length() == 0){
                password.setError("Please enter your password");
            }
```

I would have implemented a .toString and put this in a separate method and have your onClick to call on that method.

I have it working so I know it is feasible.

Answer (score 0):

you should check empty condition like:

```
if (editText.getText().toString().trim().length() = 0) {
   //editText is Empty
   editText.setError("Your message");
   return;   //add this so rest of the code will not execute
}
```

here is another way:

```
 EditText etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etname);
String strName = etName.getText().toString();

 if(TextUtils.isEmpty(strName)) {
    etName.setError("Your message");
    return;
 }
```

Also you should change your `onCreatView()` to:

```
 View view;

 @Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_login_fragment, container, false);
    login = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
    email = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.regEmailEt);
    password = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.regPasswordEt);

    return view;
}
```

Comment: i have added the "return" statment, and the application still crash

Comment: i have posted the crash log

Comment: check the edited answer..you editext is null..u need to reference it in `onCreateView()`

Comment: well its null because i dont enter anything in the textEdit. and when i press the login button i want to pop up a message with the setError to the user to fill the fields.

Comment: no your `Editext` object itself is null not the content inside it..`EditText.getText() on a null object reference`

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  String email, password;
    email = emailfield.getText().toString();
    password = passfield.getText().toString();

    if(!(email.isEmpty())) {
        if(!(password.isEmpty())) {

            //run your process here

        } else {
            passfield.setError("Password Field Empty");
        }
    } else {
        emailfield.setError("Email Empty");
    }
}
```